# Why Can't My AWS instance install node-sass pacakage?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sass, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, node-sass

I made an app using Node and am trying to host it using AWS's Elastic Beanstalk, but it always fails npm install when it reaches node-sass. Here is the error from the logs:

> 5162 error node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
>   5162 error Exit status 1
>   5163 error Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
>   5163 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   5163 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
>   5163 error not with npm itself.
>   5163 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   5163 error     node scripts/build.js
>   5163 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   5163 error     npm bugs node-sass
>   5163 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   5163 error     npm owner ls node-sass
>   5163 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>   5164 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

And here is my repository: https://github.com/Jacob-Elder/react-socket.io-messaging

[This is my aws configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0eQo.png)

I searched this issue and found some people reinstalled node-sass with the  '--unsafe-perm' flag, but this doesn't seem to be a permissions issue. I'm new to AWS and coding so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Have you found out how to solve yours?

Answer (score 3):

So I also had npm install fail on node-sass.  I get roughly the same error message as you, but then a few lines above the lines you mention in the original post, I see this "make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o] Error 127".

Judging from this similar stackexchange post: https://serverfault.com/questions/204893/aws-ec2-and-build-essential,

which in turn points to the AWS docs, you may have to run `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` to get some additional binaries