# npm create-react-app cannot create an app

Tags: reactjs, npm

It creates the files, but after the npm start command this is the error message:

Failed to compile

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Package exports for '/media/parragi/Új kötet/Web development/react projects/react-playground/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/kleur' do not define a valid './colors' target

The npm version is: 6.12.0

The create-react-app version is: 3.4.1

What should I do with it?

Comment: I've seen this error while trying to run node-sass on an ec2 linux AMI.  What environment are you working with?

Comment: I use Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58675938/12010984) worked for me.  TLDR: run `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`, then run an `npm install` again

Comment: I've just tried it but is says that there is no yum command.

Comment: Well, it was installed globally. I've removed it and installed on the folder I want to use with. I've tried to create a new react app, but I have the same error message.

Comment: someone [here](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1328) suggested manually installed autoprefixer at version 9.8.0.   You could try that

Comment: I used the link Seth mentioned. It turned out that I had a 13.0.1 node version. Removed and installed the latest version. Also installed autoprefixer 9.8.0. But I have the same error message again. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538 Please make sure that you followed correct steps to setup your react project. You can follow official docs or that answer.